# I get strange behavior of git --git-dir

Tags: git

What is difference between `git -C` and `git --git-dir` ?

Why `--git-dir` don't work with `git grep` ?

Why sometimes does `git log --git-dir=$Path/.git` work and sometimes `git log --git-dir=$Path/` work ?

Answer (score 2):

`git -C <path>` makes Git move its current working directory to the given `<path>` argument.  This potentially affects *two* searches:

1. Where should Git find the repository?
2. Where should Git find the work-tree?

On the other hand, `--git-dir <path>` tells Git where to find the repository, and `--work-tree <path>` tells Git where to find the work-tree.

When using only `-C` (and not setting the environment variable `GIT_DIR`), you get the same effect as changing your own current directory: Git will still look for `.git` in the current directory.

When using `--git-dir` or `--work-tree`, you affect only the one search.  If that search is *relative* (does not start with `/` on sane systems, or a drive-letter on others) it occurs from the current working directory, whatever that is.  If that search is *absolute* (does start with `/`, or starts with, e.g., `Z:/`), the current working directory is irrelevant to that search.

---

There's one more key item: if no specific repository location or work-tree location is given, the search is a more general kind of search.  It starts from the current directory (perhaps modified by `-C`) and works upwards, looking for a `.git` directory.  For instance, suppose the starting point is `/a/b/c/d/e`.  Git will look for:

1. `/a/b/c/d/e/.git`: If that exists, that's the repository location, and the work-tree starts here.  Otherwise:
2. `/a/b/c/d/.git`: If that exists, that's the repository location, and the work-tree starts here.  Since you're in `e/` within that directory, there may be files that require one `..`, such as `../README.md` if there is a `README.md` file in the top level.

   If that fails, though, we move on to:
3. `/a/b/c/.git`: If that exists, that's the repository location (and see step 2).  Otherwise, try:
4. `/a/b/.git`: if that exists, that's the repository location; otherwise:
5. `/a/.git`: If that exists, that's the repository location; otherwise:
6. `/.git`: If that exists, that's the repository location; otherwise:
7. fail: there is no Git repository.

But *this search is only done if there is no supplied `--git-dir`*.  If a `--git-dir` is given, that's where the repository *must* exist; if it's not there, Git simply fails.

Some commands, such as `git log`, can work without a work-tree.  (If you are using such a command, you can use `--git-dir` to point it directly to the Git repository, which need not even *have* a work-tree: it may be a `--bare` repository.)  If you instead use `-C` to set your current working directory somewhere within the work-tree, the command will use the "climb up towards `/`" search method outlined above.

Comment: Can you give me example with git grep ? @torek

Comment: @Alex: `git grep` "Look[s] for specified patterns in the tracked files in the work tree, ..."  The ... part adds more places it looks, but that's if you use certain flag arguments. Since it looks in the work-tree, it matters where you are in the work-tree when you start. Then, since `--work-tree` specifies the exact location of the top of the work-tree, if you set that, that's where `git grep` looks for those files. Otherwise `git grep` starts from the *current* directory, whatever that is, and `git -C <path>` will affect that. Apply the above rules as for all Git commands to follow the rest.

Comment: git ls-files also used with --work-tree ? I don't understand when can't I use with -C ? @torek

Comment: @Alex: `git ls-files` "Show[s] information about files in the index and the working tree". It therefore must find the index (whose location depends on the Git dir and sometimes the work-tree) and, depending on options, may also need to find the work-tree. You can use `-C` and/or `--git-dir` and/or `--work-tree` with `git ls-fiiles`. Remember that all three of these options come *before* the command (`git -C dir`) while options to the command itself come *after* the commit (`git ls-files --stage`, for instance).

Comment: Note that *every single Git command is potentially different* in terms of requiring Git directory and/or work-tree. The `git` front end command handles the `-C`, `--git-dir`, and/or `--work-tree` options, and then having done so, runs the individual command that may or may not pay attention to the setup that the front end command established.

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand. Before, you said that in some case It has difference between C and (--git-dir and/or --work-tree) @torek

Comment: There are definite differences between `-C` and the other options. But they are all options to the front end `git` command, that affect how it sets things up for the individual commands that then use what the front end command sets up. The answer above describes the operation and interaction of the three options, but not whether and how any individual command uses any of what the front end `git` sets up.

Answer (score 1):

`git -C foo --git-dir=bar` is equivalent to `git --git-dir=foo/bar`.

If `bar` is a bare repository, then `--git-dir=bar/`.

If `bar` is a non-bare repository, then `--git-dir=bar/.git`.